# What filters the output voltage in those switching regulators (boost and buck-boost) which don't have a direct LC filter?

Tags: buck, boost

In a buck converter, the LC filter sees a pulsating voltage at its input, and the output is an almost DC voltage. However in other non-isolated converter topologies where the inductor is not connected to the output capacitor all the time, how does the switching node voltage get filtered? In a Boost converter, the inductor is connected to the output capacitor only when the high side FET is ON. Even when it is connected, the LC filter "sees" a DC voltage at the input. I have two questions here:

1. What filters the output voltage and what is the input to such a filter in this case?
2. If it's not apparent that the output voltage is not a DC (as in a buck), how do you know that the converter is going to reach a steady-state?

[image: Non-Synchronous DCDC Boost Converter]

Comment: That `M3` acts as a controlled diode. If you replace it with a diode, you get a basic rectifier with an R||C load.

Comment: It might help to **not** see the L and C in a boost converter as a **filter**. Instead, the inductor is **charged** (M2 is on) for a while making the current in the coil increase. Then M2 turns off and M3 turns on, now the coil is **discharged** trough M2 into C2 and the load. The current through the inductor has a triangle shape. That triangle shape current charges the capacitor. This results in a DC voltage + triangle shaped ripple voltage across C2.